# TimeoutError: timed out while using public broker in mqtt

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

When I use a local broker, namely localhost, the program can run, but when I use a public broker such as the Eclipse Project, the program cannot run and has an error

```
TimeoutError: timed out
```

Can someone help to fix the error?
Here is the code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import datetime

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("Message received: ", message.payload.decode("utf-8"))

broker_address = "mqtt.eclipse.org"
client = mqtt.Client("P1")
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect(broker_address, port=1883)  # The default MQTT port is 1883

client.loop_start()

while True:
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    client.publish("house/bulbs/bulb1", current_time)
    print(f"Published: {current_time}")
    time.sleep(1)

client.loop_stop()
```

Comment: `mqtt.eclipse.org` doesn't exist any more, `mqtt.eclipseprojects.io` is the current eclipse test broker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another strongly recommended free public MQTT broker is `broker.emqx.io`!!!

I often do some tests on it and it works very well.